# how to use System.Windows.Vector in uwp

Tags: c#, .net, windows, reference, uwp

It seems that I can't use the `System.Windows.Vector` struct in my **UWP** project and have to write my own, which is boring. Is there any way out?

P.S. : I can't reference to WindowsBase.dll because it says *This component is already automatically referenced by the build system*

Comment: It isn't incredibly complicated, you can just [take it from the ReferenceSource](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/Vector.cs).

Comment: I am pretty sure Vector is available in UWP

Comment: Yes, that's what I was looking for. Thanks. Let me mark it as an answer.

Comment: @maccettura what is the namespace path then?

Comment: @MDMuziburRahman `System.Windows` works in UWP as far as I know (but take it with a grain of salt because I am not a UWP expert), or you could use [`Vector2`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.foundation.numerics.vector2) in `Windows.Foundation.Numerics`

Comment: @maccettura Thanks for Vector2, and yes, System.Windows is in **UWP**, but it has only one class : `System.Windows.Input` nothing else, you can check it. I tried . the error message is like: *The type or namespace name 'Vector' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)*

Comment: @maccettura also, Vector2 isn't available either.  check it yourself: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Foundation

Comment: @MDMuziburRahman Look at the link I provided for `Vector2`, its _literally_ in the UWP Api Documentation.  Or better yet go to the [API browser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/) for UWP, type in: "Windows.Foundation.Numerics"

Comment: You can also try using [System.Numerics.Vectors-4.5.0-preview1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Numerics.Vectors/4.5.0-preview1-26216-02) that targets .NET Standard 1.6.1